# Is it a good practice to allow users to embed raw sql queries in an application?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns

I tried my best to come up with an appropriate title, excuses if it doesn't make much sense. I hope to explain it better below. We have an application that is based on .Net framework and uses SQL as data storage. As with any application, this application need to support extensibility, for example to support additional data transformations & validations.

**Example:** Think of the application as a tool that provides a set of input tables the user can import data into using access or excel (there is UI & grids already) to allow data import. Once the data is imported the tool creates an intermediate model and performs some calculations on the input data and later throws the results in pre-defined format. The input table schema and intermediate model schema is fixed, no changes will happen. The extensibility is needed in the stage where the intermediate model is derived from the input data. Allow users to be able to change the way the data gets derived, eg instead of grouping by one field allow grouping by multiple fields etc.

To support this kind of flexibility, I see there are two basic approaches as I could see

Option 1: Create a business model that maps to the sql data model and expose the business model to the user to allow them to override transformations & create new transformations (e.g., using LINQ or plain C#)

Option 2: Expose the entire sql data model and allow users to embed raw SQL queries to perform the transformations & validations.

My personal preference is to use Option 1, since I am not a big fan of allowing users to play with underlying data tables directly. I prefer more controlled access. However, this approach requires the user to have programming language (C# or VB). On the other hand Option 2, may just need someone who has knowledge of SQL programming to create raw queries and directly plug them into the application. But, I think this is a bad approach.

The product management team is inclined to go with Option 2, as they feel it is more flexible and easy to implement from resource point of view.

So, I am trying to come up with pros and cons of both approach to better support my inclination for Option 1. Basically, inclination to do the work in programming language in C# or VB .net rather than just using plain SQL queries.

Kindly, share your thoughts and opinions.

Comment: Do you mean to allow users to embed queries like DROP TABLE Students; ?

Comment: Oh little Bobby Tables!

Comment: @BobKaufman Mostly CREATE TABLES, SELECT INTO, UPDATE etc. To better explain, let's say there is Table A and B. Allow a user to query data from Table A and insert into Table B

Comment: How hard can it be to create a list of possible fields and a list of possible criteria and generate a SQL.  The user should never have to write their own SQL, they might end up with results that they think are right and base decisions regarding the company business model on the data and that is the worst thing that can happen.

Comment: @user320587 - If you can provide a specific example, I can update my answer to address it.

Comment: @Bobson added an example to the post

Comment: @user320587 - Edited.  See what you think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Neither option is a good one.**

End users are (theoretically) proficient in the business logic - they shouldn't need to be proficient in a programming language to do their job.

What you should do is create a framework for extending things using standard controls - combo boxes, text input, grids, etc.  It's hard to give you specific advice without specifics of what kind of extensibility you're looking for, but I'll give you an example from my projects:

Our users need a way to add arbitrary tags to products, for filtering on our website.  We created a data grid where they could type in the name of a type, specify whether it's a "True/False", integer, decimal, or a value off of a list, and then set the items for said list.  Then, on each product, they are presented with the list of all the applicable types and they need to fill in values - the "True/False" produces a checkbox, the integer and decimal produce text fields which validate, and the list produces a combo box of all the options they specified.  Whenever they want a new property, they can go add it themselves, but they don't need to think about how those properties work at all, because the website operates based on the *type*.

---

Ok, based on your example, I would suggest this:

Provide a form which lists every column of the data and has a combo box next to it to specify what action to take.  The actions can be chosen from a list which contains things like:

- Ignore data
- Use data as-is
- Format data
- Look up value elsewhere
- Perform calculation

Based on the user's choice in this dropdown, you would:

- Not include the column in the output
- Use the data as-is.
- Provide a button to open a form where they can format the data (probably with a subset of the `String.Format` options) based on the type of the data.  You'd show a key on the bottom to show what values are supported.
- Provide a button to specify what "elsewhere" is.  *This is probably where extensibility will be most useful, so I'll address it again below*
- Provide a way to enter an appropriate calculation.

As for the "elsewhere" lookup, this would probably be mostly  listings of values  and strings to transform it with.  Those values can be specified in a configuration section of the application, and stored in a table somewhere.  You can create arbitrary groupings of them to represent various "lists" of options.  Alternatively, you could list some existing data tables which you would want the users to reference, and let them specify a transformation (using the calculation screen) to convert their value to a lookup on the other table.

Is this making sense?

Comment: Thanks Bobson. Think of the application has a set of input tables, the user import data from excel or access etc. Once, the data is imported, the application creates a new model from the input data and performs some calculations on it and throws the results out. The extensibility is to override the way the new model is derived from the input tables.

Comment: @user320587 - So you don't know beforehand what columns are going to be in the excel data?  You just generate them as needed?

Comment: Bobson. The input model schema and the intermediate model schema is fixed. But, the extensibility is needed on how we derive the intermediate model from input model.

Comment: Thanks Bob. It does make sense. But, all this additional development stuff is going to be a tough sell. But, going to give a try. Thanks so much for your suggestions. In your suggestions, the elsewhere component is going to be the toughest since the transformations could get quite complex involving lot of lookups and UNIONS etc.

Comment: @user320587 - I'd suggest getting some of the people involved in *using* it into the meeting and presenting them with the three options. "You can learn SQL, you can learn to program, or we can take more time and make this easy for you." :)   It's actually not that likely to take longer than option #1, since the logic would be much simpler.